# form is processed in spite of doing a return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code:

```js
preSearch: function() {
  var IdValue = $('[name="Id"]').val();
  if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(IdValue)) {
    alert("Please only enter numeric characters");
    return false;
  }
}
```

But after displaying the alert, when I click 'OK'. The execution continues and the form is being processed. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: What is `preSearch`? This is obviously part of some larger object, probably configuring a library.

Comment: @Newbee can you elaborate, where this is used or code?

Comment: what I;m trying to do is search for an Id value. If it is not numeric. Im throwing the alert on clicking the 'Submit' button. We are using various methods/calls for eg preSave, postInitcallback, presearch in the jsp page.

Comment: How you calling this function on submit button ?